# Listing Bluetooth printers while scaning Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth

I am developing an Android application (flutter). My requirement is only needed to display  Bluetooth printers.  Now when scanning all devices are listed. Any option to filter only Bluetooth printing services?

```
import 'package:esc_pos_utils/esc_pos_utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';

FlutterBlue flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance;

 void findDevices() {
    
    flutterBlue.startScan(
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 4),
    );
    // scanResult= flutterBlue.connectedDevices
    flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
      setState(() {
        scanResult = results;
      });
    });
    flutterBlue.stopScan();
  }
```

My scanning code.

Comment: I don't think you can scanning only bluetooth printer device. But you can filter the result then only show bluetooth printer. First, you need to list all UUID of any available bluetooth printer. Some of them use same generic UUID `0001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`. Then, from the scanResult, check with those list of UUID, if match, then put it in a list to display to user.

Comment: is there any method to find a printing device?

Comment: With flutter_blue, I don't think you can scan only bluetooth printer device like I said above. If you're using flutter_blue, my proposed solution is described above. But you might check [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_print), never tried that package, but it might works.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible solution for filtering while scanning or scanning only Bluetooth printer devices. But filter the result then only show.